# Children’s fantasy book about triplet sisters: one speaks to animals, one can turn into an animal and the last harnesses water

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Read this book back in the 2000s. I remember bits and pieces of it:

Triplet sisters (Hendersons I think), one has the ability to speak to animals, one can turn into an animal, panther or something, and the last can harness water power. All three have different hair colors. The father can turn into a bear and they have a tutor that speaks through a computer. They are hunted by this evil being that can teleport through mirrors. This entity can shapeshift I believe. That’s all I remember. Looking for the title if anyone knows this book!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Trillium-Sisters-Triplets-Get-Charmed/dp/164595014X is close, but different powers and their father is a veterinarian.

Comment: @DavidW I have a vague memory but it was this yellow cover with a girl on it. Not the most helpful but that’s my 10 year old memory there 

Comment: I remember the mother of the three girls sacrificed herself to open a portal for the girls and their dad to escape… This monster that is hunting them is able to teleport through reflective surfaces and is a subordinate to a powerful witch who seeks to acquire the water power which one of the triplets has.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is this one but I vaguely remember a similar concept in this collection of kids books. The Sisters Grimm: The Fairy-Tale Detectives" by Michael Buckley

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see how this fits at all. It seems to be about two orphaned sisters (not twins/triplets) and they don't seem to have powers.